# Macosx yosemite installing mysql-python config error

Tags: python, mysql, mamp, mysql-python

I am trying install mysql-python but always throw error. The command is "pip install mysql-python". I searched in google and tried everything but i am still getting error.

I am using mamp, MAMP's path is "/Applications/MAMP". I tested mysql with php and there is no error, mysql is working. I also connected to mysql by navicat. I am sure that mysql is installed and it is working.

I put the error screenshoot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need libmysqlclient.so library to be able to install MySQLdb,
Which come with MySQL Server and client and can also be downloaded with MySQL Connector/C.
Locate the library and set your DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to have the path where libmysqlclient.so is present.